# Can we use an icon in ACE editor's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I know that I can add an autocomplete list in ACE editor as below

```
completions.push({ name:"testing1", value:"testing1", meta: "code1" });
completions.push({ name:"testing2", value:"testing2", meta: "code2" });
```

My requirement is to add an icon adjacent to "code1" in the autocomplete popup. I tried to use `<img>` in meta value but it didn't work. I saw the ace's source code but didn't see a way to implement it.

Has anyone done this before?

**Update**:
I did it myself and added details in the answer below

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work.

Comment: @Soviut, I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it through css.

Added `className` property to the completion object

```
completions.push({ name:"test", value:"test", meta: "test", className:"iconable"});
```

And added icon in css:

```
.ace_iconable:after
{
    content: " \f14c"; /* in my case it is font-awesome icon*/
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an `<img>` tag in the `meta` text won't work because it isn't interpreted as HTML.

If you can include additional information in your autocomplete objects, you could:

```
completions.push({ name:"testing1", value:"testing1", meta: "code1", icon: "code1.png" });
```

From there, you could find the code that creates the autocomplete popup and add a conditional if statement that optionally adds an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Would you please help me to get the hook (in ace) to modify the code to insert the icon. I see that a module "ace/autocomplete/popup" uses the completion data to define tokens, but I am not sure how to override this to use our icon property and also to render it .

Comment: I don't know either. Unless you have some code, try the Ace forums for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ace.Tern extension supports using an iconClass property in autocomplete extension. See [it on github](https://github.com/sevin7676/Ace.Tern/blob/8e761681855cd1280862e8c44350a0f7cb723c00/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ext-tern.js#L1108)

However this is not something currently in Ace editor. I would say if you need to support just static styles, using className property (see [it on github](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/29be0850e38130a29ade6694c4a9b8604b8cae23/lib/ace/autocomplete/popup.js#L190)) and using before pseudo class to load them. In my case I need to do some post processing of the items in autocomplete popups, hence I need to listen to the 'afterRender' events like [this one](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/29be0850e38130a29ade6694c4a9b8604b8cae23/lib/ace/autocomplete/popup.js#L134) so that I can dynamically inject my icons in it.